# Removing spaces from dictionaries key-value pairs

Tags: python

So this is my code for a program adding dicts together.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def add_sparse_vectors(lst1,lst2):
    dest = dict(Counter(lst1)+Counter(lst2))
    return dest
```

This is my current output:

```
>>> v1 = {0:1, 1:3, 2:1}
>>> v2 = {0:1}
>>> add_sparse_vectors(v1, v2)
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1}
```

Problem is that my assignment asks for this output specifically:

```
>>> v1 = {0:1, 1:3, 2:1}
>>> v2 = {0:1}
>>> add_sparse_vectors(v1, v2)
{0:2, 1:3, 2:1}
#Note the lack of spaces between the colon and the value in each pair.
```

Does anyone have a solution for removing this specific space from the key-value pairs in the output? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the assignment is fulfilled.  You would need to create your own `dict` class, etc. to get that exact output.  (unless you actually want to return a string.)  Whoever gave the assignment probably left out the spaces to make it more clear which are the keys and which are the values.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was just worried because my TA mentioned that I need the exact output given in the assignment sheet to receive credit. It seems rather trivial though, hopefully I'll be fine.

Comment: Is the line `#Note the lack of spaces...` part of the assignment, or is that your note?

Comment: That is my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to get rid of the spaces, you don't need to implement a custom `dict` class, like @zondo suggested. The assignment only requires the representation to have no spaces. If `add_sparse_vectors` returns a string instead of a dictionary, you don't need to change `dict`'s behavior.

Although I don't think this is particularly elegant, it does get rid of the spaces.

```
def add_sparse_vectors(v1, v2):
    combined_dict = dict(Counter(lst1)+Counter(lst2))
    key_val_pairs = [str(k)+":"+str(v) for k,v in combined_dict.items()]
    output = "{" + ", ".join(key_val_pairs) + "}"
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write your own print function for dictionaries:

```
def print_dict(d):
    print('{'+', '.join('{}:{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in d.items())+'}')
```

This does what your exercise asks for, but actually I think that they should not care about having some whitespaces more or less as long as the task is solved correctly...